# How to link the x-axis of different plots? (subplot not used) [Python/Plotly-Dash]

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I just wanted to know if it is possible to link different figures x-axes (as it can be done using subplots with shared_xaxes) in order to see the same range once zoom in or zoom out are performed. I highlight 'different figures'.

Thank you.